what is the difference in Googe play store on "archived apk" and "signed, universal apk"?

In google console, I can download my app by different format, like above.
So my question is, what is the difference on "archived apk" and "signed, universal apk"?
Thanks.
I expect the answer of my question.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/03/freeing-up-60-of-storage-for-apps.html

Archiving is a new functionality that will allow users to reclaim ~60% of app storage temporarily by removing parts of the app rather than uninstalling it completely. An archived app will remain on the device and can easily be restored to the latest available compatible version, whilst preserving the user data.


As we are taking steps toward making archiving available to all developers, we will start generating a new type of APK - archived APKs - for developers using the App Bundle to publish their app. Archived APKs are very small APKs that preserve user data until the app is restored. While we will start creating archived APKs now, they won’t be functional until the archiving functionality is launched to consumers later in the year.

Auto-archive was introduced back in 2023 as a Google Play feature and will get OS level support in Android 15
